# Sublime Text 2 Slowness with Emmet

Tags: sublimetext2, emmet

I recently installed Emmet on sublime text 2 and since then I have been noticing a lot of slowness when working with large files.

One file I am working with has 1500 lines and whenever I hit "tab" after typing an html/tag short cut Sublime Text 2 becomes unresponsive for about 10-15 seconds...

When I work with smaller files, this is not an issue at all. When I uninstall Emmet/PyV8 performance on the larger files returns to normal.

I have searched here and other forums and haven't found much on subject but was wondering if there some other plugin/setting I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've just spent a while this morning trying to revive my installation which becomes slow after a period of time.

I eventually succeeded by [reverting to a fresh state](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/revert.html), renaming (moving) the data folder. The packages you have downloaded can be copied across from the renamed old data folder - don't forget package manager.

A little cross-testing seems to indicate that the culprits were the session file in Settings and the project files themselves, so create new project files.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes ST2 slows down because the Data/Settings/Settigs.sublime_session gets too big to handle, take a backup of that file and remove it, sublime will recreate it and it will be like 2kb or something ( the new one) Sometimes the session file gets too big, it stores recently accesssed files, find history, replace history etc. etc. you can take a look at it, its a text file.
all the best.